# error command errored out with exit status 1 pip install

Tags: python, mysql, pip, virtualenv, mysql-python

I use python vitrualenv and when I want to install any packages by `pip install <package name>` I take that error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/user/project/some_project_name/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sifdsjjx/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sifdsjjx/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-sifdsjjx/MySQL-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sifdsjjx/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sifdsjjx/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sifdsjjx/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I use python 3.7.0
pip 20.0.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-python%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+ConfigParser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to upgrade [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

---

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, you are attempting to install [`MySQL-python`](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/#history) which is a very old package (last release was made back in 2014).

You can however install a more recent one, called [`MySQLdb`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) which is a thin python wrapper around C module which implements API for MySQL database:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: ```Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (46.1.3)```

Comment: @МаксимЩедров What package are you trying to install?

Comment: I  am trying to install MySQL-python package

Comment: @МаксимЩедров I updated my answer. Hope it helps now.

Comment: Yes, it's helped me thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the SQL client dev pacakge on your system?

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

if you are using mariadb, the drop in replacement for mysql, then run

```
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev
```

then try again