# pip fully install package first after installing other package

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

My requirements.txt looks like this:

```
cloudpickle==1.6.0
gym==0.19.0
msgpack-python==0.5.6
msgpack-rpc-python==0.4.1
numpy==1.19.5
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.4.60
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
py-trees==2.1.6
pydot==1.4.2
pyparsing==3.0.6
tornado==4.5.3
airsim==1.6.0
```

Now I execute `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir`

It will try to download everything first, but then I receive an error at package "airsim" that numpy is not installed yet:

[image]

In fact, when looking into the virtual environment, it did not install numpy yet but downloaded it instead:

[image]

The only way to make it work is to pip install the packages separately and airsim at last. However, is there a way that pip will fully install the first packages first and after completion, install airsim at last? Or is there a way to skip the "Preparing metadata" step for airsim package

Comment: What version of python/pip are you using? Check using `python --version` and `pip --version`. Such errors can happen when the Python version and the package version are not compatible. Have you tried [upgrading setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525119/error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-pip-install)?

Comment: @NikhilKumar yes i did. im using python 3.7.9 and pip 21.3.1 . after creating an venv i always execute this command: 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools --no-cache-dir

Comment: i dont think this is a compability issue. have you tried it yourself? does every package get installed without any issues for you? i believe the developers of "airsim" package did a mistake perhaps